# How to adjust the ui of website on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, css, ios, user-interface

So i have a website and everything works fine on PC but when you open it from a phone the website is moved by the navigation menu of the mobile browser. The height of the website is exactly 100vh but displaced by the navigation bar

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include more detail such as what frameworks you are using. Provide a minimal reproduction on a software like stackblitz.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the solution to your problem:
https://chanind.github.io/javascript/2019/09/28/avoid-100vh-on-mobile-web.html

Basically use javascript with window.innerHeight instead of CSS